# The background <div> leave space after it, when i try to make the screen smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4. When i put a div background and make the screen smaller, it leaves a lot of space between him and the new div.

I don't really know how to fix it. Maybe i can fix somehow the height of the div? The idea is that i am trying to make the background of the div and all his content, to make as larger as the resolution of the monitor, even if its destroys the quality of the image.

```css
.gg{
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
}

/*Fara marigini in parti*/
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}


.newbg {
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/L0Ls4Nz/bg.png);
  height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
}

.pp
{
 background-color: green;
 background-size: 1920px 1080px;
 height: 100vh;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Bootstrap Lessons</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <!-- Stilurile mele -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">


 <!-- Fisier spre jQuery -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <!-- Fisier spre javascript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js" async></script>

 <!-- FontAwesome - Icons -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body class="gg">
<header>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xl-12 nopadding">
 
    <div class="newbg">
    </div>
    <div class="pp"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot: 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: use `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 0):

You can use min-height instead of heigh. Also you can control the heigth of element using mediaqueries for differents resolutions. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.newbg {
  height: 50px;
}
}
```

Maybe if the image is not a pattern, the better solution is use the image directly. Using the class img-fluid. If you don't want to accept selection for the image, you can add:

```
    .noselect {-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera */
```

}

I hope you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with background-size:cover in .newbg class

```
.newbg {
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/L0Ls4Nz/bg.png);
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. In this case, I get only a part of the background, no the full size version. I mean that instead of full width size, I see only a piece of the picture, but the other details and the user can't see them. Is there another solution for that? Like the same, but the width should not be covered, I want to see the full background.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your problem is only CSS related. I'll encourage you to learn the stack (without frameworks): [freecodecamp](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/) is a great place to start.

About your question: as other users have already pointed out: `background-size: cover;` will fix your issue.

But you'll also probably want the image centered; `background-position: center;`: will do the trick. Note that this is a shortcut for `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`. So you could also use it like: `background-position: center top;`

I will also recommend you to use the property `min-height: 100vh;` and then `height: auto;`. So your image will be always *at least* even height as the browser's viewport, but it will grow, if the content inside the div is larger.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. In this case, I get only a part of the background, no the full size version. I mean that instead of full width size, I see only the center of the picture, but the details from the right and left are hidden by screen and the user can't see them. Is there another solution for that? Like the same, but the width should not be covered, I want to see the full background.